# Prisma GraphQL Belongs To and Has Many Relations

Tags: graphql, prisma

I'm learning Prisma GraphQL and trying to create a belongs to and has many relations, but when deploying it fails.

The scenario:

- User will have a list of created comments
- User will have a list of comments
- Comment will belongs to an author (User)
- Comment will have an user (commented User)

What I've tried:

```
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
  roles: [Role!]!

  profile: Profile! @relation(name: "Profile", onDelete: CASCADE)
  addresses: [Address!]! @relation(name: "AddressAuthor", onDelete: CASCADE)
  posts: [Post!]! @relation(name: "PostAuthor", onDelete: CASCADE)
  topics: [Topic!]! @relation(name: "TopicAuthor", onDelete: CASCADE)
  subjects: [Subject!]! @relation(name: "SubjectAuthor", onDelete: CASCADE)
  votes: [Vote!]! @relatiion(name: "VoteAuthor", onDelete: CASCADE)
  notifications: [Notification!]! @relation(name: "Notification", onDelete: CASCADE)

  createdFollows: [Follow!]! @relation(name: "FollowAuthor", onDelete: CASCADE)
  followers: [Follow!]! @relation(name: "FollowedUser", onDelete: CASCADE)

  createdComments: [Comment!]! @relation(name: "CommentAuthor", onDelete: CASCADE)
  comments: [Comment!]! @relation(name: "CommentedUser")
}

type Comment {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  author: User! @relation(name: "CommentAuthor")

  type: String!
  body: String!
  attachments: [Attachment!]! @relation(name: "CommentAttachment", onDelete: CASCADE)
  comments: [Comment!]! @relation(name: "CommentComment", onDelete: CASCADE)
  likes: [Like!]!
  followers: [Follow!]!

  user: User @relation(name: "CommentedUser", onDelete: CASCADE)
  post: Post
  topic: Topic
  subject: Subject
  comment: Comment @relation(name: "CommentComment")
}
```

But when trying to deploy it, I got error to fix the ambiguity between `Comment` and `User`. So, can you help me how to correctly define the relations? `Post`, `User` and even `Comment` can have many comments.

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried your example and could deploy the datamodel you showed without any issues. Did you show your entire datamodel or are there any missing types? In any case, it seems like your issue is somewhere else?! @nanang-mahdaen-el-agung

Comment: @nburk thanks for the response. I've updated the question. So, when I remove the `commentedUsers` and `comments` from the `User` and remove the `user` from `Comment` and remove the relation name of `Comment` `author`, the deploy just fine. Am I doing wrong when naming the relation?